# How can I connect from Mac OS X to Windows through a Wi-Fi router?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

I have two computers and a [D-Link DAP-1350](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dap-1350-wireless-n-pocket-router-and-access-point) router. The DHCP server configuration is:

- **Router:** `192.168.1.1`
- **Mac:** `192.168.1.2`
- **Windows:** `192.168.1.3`

Both (Mac and Windows) have the same workgroup.

But if I try to `ping 192.168.1.3` from Mac I get:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq
```

I want to share folder to Windows.

How can I get to the folder if I can’t even ping it?

Answer (score 1):

Check firewalls, disable firewall on the Mac and enable ping in Windows.
Are you able to access Internet from both Mac and Windows?

Search for Windows Firewall, and click to open it. Note:

- Click “Advanced Settings” on the left.
- From the left pane of the resulting window, click “Inbound Rules.”
- In the right pane, find the rules titled “File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In).”
- Right-click each rule and choose “Enable Rule.”